# states are not loaded according to selected country

Tags: ruby-on-rails

pls guys,am using the country_state_select gem,after inputing the codes from the documentation,the country and state select tags are displayed properly on the form view,but the states are not loaded even after a country is selected,the only states i see are the states in United States of America(USA),i added my javascript,yet the problem persists.
this is my .js file below

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {

return CountryStateSelect({
country_id: "admin_country",
state_id: "admin_state"
})
})
```

admin_country and admin_state are my IDs for the country and state fields respectively.

Comment: Did you ever solved it? I am having the same issue. CountryStateSelect produces a Uncaught ReferenceError, same story for @import "chosen" at .css.scss... All is in place, ids are ok, gem country_state_select just seems to lack better configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. Tested and working. Found it at the gem itself, inside issues...

https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select/issues/31

Includes this code:

> <%= javascript_include_tag "country_state_select" %> <%=
>   javascript_tag do %> $(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
>   return CountryStateSelect({
>       country_id: "country",
>       state_id: "state"   }); });

But needs an extra line at config/initializers/assets.rb

> Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
>   country_state_select.js )

Thanks to @loganh0522 solution is from 4 days ago...

Comment: NO, i could not solve the issue,but i will try yours anyway..thanks